# 2 ajax query into JS [google maps]

Tags: ajax, google-maps

This my code. 
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqfYK/)

I get data from mysql by xml.
it`s work fine.
but iu must get second query from mysql by xml like this. but it does not work.  script stopped work.  how can i do 2 or more ajax query into JS file?..

this part i wrote manually. it must be generated by script.. but when i do this by xml (by ajax) script would`t work :(

Sorry for my english.

```
       flightPlanCoordinates = [
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9921196514,47.8604733650 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9922511293,47.8606186245 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9926358563,47.8611079146 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9929381070,47.8615028229 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9931715315,47.8620863814 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9933869955,47.8623375976 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9936024589,47.8625888155 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9942600516, 47.8634730879 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9946698905, 47.8639284456),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9951427577,47.8643998201 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9956477404 ,47.8648835770),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9959645185, 47.8651699964),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9962812958, 47.8654564186 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9965401588,47.8657069220 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9970324883 ,47.8661781983),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9972659548, 47.8663989707 ),
                 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9975468767, 47.8664409273),
                 new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9978740427,47.8662277913 ),
                new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9982012084,47.8660150777 ),
                    new google.maps.LatLng( 40.9985497469,47.8658461824),
 new google.maps.LatLng(40.9988327045,47.8660951747),
  new google.maps.LatLng(40.9991045183,47.8664072712),                
   new google.maps.LatLng(40.9992585926,47.8665868156),                    





        ];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          strokeColor: '#FF0040',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);



  google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath,'mouseover', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: '#3ADF00' });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 4 });
  });

     google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath,'mouseout', function() {


        this.setOptions({strokeColor: '#FF0040' });
           this.setOptions({strokeOpacity: 1.0 });
           this.setOptions({strokeWeight: 2 });
  });




       var mpenc = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var contentString ="informasiya burada olacaq ";
  google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath,'click', function(event) {
    mpenc.setContent(contentString);
    mpenc.setPosition(event.latLng);
    mpenc.open(map);
  });
```

---

When i add second ajax query script stopped . why ? i cant use 2 or more ajax query same moment?? please help..

```
 // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("gxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

}
```

Comment: the link to jsFiddle is missing

Comment: Are you trying to put the polygon coordinates into the xml as well?  I don't see any attempt to do that in your jsfiddle.

Comment: yes i`d do it. but when i attempt to put xml file script stopped working. maybe 2 or more xml data will not work same js?